# HDR5_DIR-NOTFOUND error

Tags: cmake, hdf5, flann

I built the [parallel version of HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/PHDF5/). Then I tried to build [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/) through cmake-gui.

Since the `HDF5_DIR` was signed as `HDF5_DIR-NOTFOUND` I tried with `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-mpi-dev` (I have already installed `mpicc`), but nothing changed.

I think that if this entry will not change then I'll problems the `make` phase (especially because I want to execute FLANN in parallel with MPI and OpenMP).

Comment: Clear your CMake cache and rerun.

Comment: `HDF5_DIR` should point to directory with `hdf5-config.cmake` file (or similar). Find this file in your HDF5 installation and set variable accordingly.